# How to create text block over the images with css and make it responsive

Tags: html, css

I just want to ask, How to make text block on image, I was got it but when it < 720px the text block is change and it's look not beautiful, I want the txt block is always in the same position as 1024px,

this is my css script

```
.text-block { position : absolute; bottom: 0px; left:0px; }
```

it's look good when > 1024 px, but when  < 720px it's look bad

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30Bs8.png)

I'm sorry if my english is bad

Comment: could you setup a minimal example? **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)**

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/v9ytp8h0/) I want the textblock is always in that place however the size is minimize or maximize

Comment: Do you want it to be responsive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've wrapped your image and the block text in a div with class `category` , the div itself has `position: relative`, so the absolute positioning of the `.category-header` is related to `.category`. Take a look at the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwachtler/pewxrxhx/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="category">
    <div class="category-header">
         <h4>Politik</h4>
    </div>
    <img src="http://tvberita.com/foto_berita/8dedi%20mulyadi.jpg">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.category {
    position: relative;
}
.category > img {
    display: block;
}
.category-header {
    background-color: #870000;
    display: block;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family:"Oswald", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.category-header h4 {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you're my hero, css make me so confused.

Comment: You're welcome, if you search for some good resources to learn CSS, check the **[Mozilla Developer Network | CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS)** out

Answer (score 1):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/51/

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">
    <div class="text">
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
    position: relative;
}

.text {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 10px 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: No problem bro, glad i could help.